# RegEx to replace a particular pattern v-q- to q- and v- to q- .

Tags: c#, regex, replace, match

I am new to Regex.

The sentence is something like this

```
string ttt = "Becoming a <a href=\"/v-abc-q-def-ghi.aspx\">Lorem ipsum</a> or <a href=\"/v-xyz.aspx\">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy "
```

I want to change all patterns that match
**v-abc-q-def-ghi** to **q-def-ghi** 
**v-xyz** to **q-xyz**

The requirement is if v- and q- is present, I should remove v-* and 
if it only has v-* then it should be changed to q-*.

var matches = Regex.Match(ttt, "v-*-q-*"); - I get 0 matches . I tried a few mor ethings using ([a-z])\?([a-z]) and some characters, but could not figure out :(

Kindly help me with this. Is this really achievable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something like what you were looking for?

```
Regex.Replace(ttt, @"\/(v-[^\.]*?q-|v-)", "/q-");
```

[Example](http://regexr.com/3asa4)

Comment: Yes it solved the first part of problem.  How to handle the second part ?

Comment: What is the second problem?

Comment: the second problem is v-xyz to q-xyz    (there is no q- in the string to replace)